# extract data from a url which contains compressed data

Tags: java

I am doing a project which uses stack overflow API and I want to extract data from a  URL but i think it contains compressed data so how to extract these data in java.

URL:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&fromdate=1031640800&todate=1231681791&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&key=Z19xwkOfreckWgqMe7OiZg((&access_token=rPoIwGm9ZpRpqU4HG7WWDQ))&tagged=php&filter=withbody
```

can anybody please help me

Comment: That URL returns a MIME type of application/json, so its content is a JSON data structure. This is not compressed, but you will need a JSON parser to easily extract data from it. Also, I think you are supposed to keep your `key` and/or `access_token` values a secret, so you probably should not post them online.

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression

Comment: Please any one can give more ideas how to do it